# Can I use regedit to change the wallpaper path on windows 10 enterprise?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, desktop-customization

I just purchased a second hand HP Elitebook but it looks like it was an ex-lease model and has windows 10 enterprise installed. I can't personalize the PC because enterprise isn't activated (eventually I will downgrade to win10 home or pro). Is there a way to edit the registry so that I can add a custom wallpaper? That's all I want to change.

This seems to be the path to the one and only wallpaper available.
C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Windows\img0.jpg

I've tried simply replacing the img0.jpg file with a picture the same name, file type, and dimensions but it doesn't work. It looks like permissions are locked for this too.

Comment: A 2nd hand laptop that was sold to you with an unactived enterprise install on it...That's a bit weird. Ex lease or not. The seller should provide a retail license (Home or Pro) or sell the laptop "without OS".

Comment: I got it from a pawn shop and they had restored the OS. I'm not complaining though, it was a great deal. Mistaken identity I think. These HPs are powerhouses but have the appearance of budget chromebooks.

Comment: I see.. More a case of just not knowing the difference I presume.  You should be able to "downgrade" Enterprise to Pro Home if you have a key. There may actually be a key on the laptop. Take a look inside the battery compartment if the key isn't on the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the wallpaper using the Local Group Policy Editor
(`gpedit.msc`), at
*User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Desktop > Desktop*,
group policy "Desktop Wallpaper". Set the policy to Enabled, enter the
file path and click OK.

In the registry, this is set at key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
(you may need to create missing sub-keys).
Create two REG_SZ items, one named `Wallpaper` for the path to the
image file, and the other `WallpaperStyle` whose value is `4`.

For more information, see the article
[How to Specify Default Desktop Background in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/91437-specify-default-desktop-background-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Will Windows honor this policy if it is set via the registry? Windows 10 and later ignore some policies completely if the keys are made manually (without being set by group-policy) or if the Windows license is not activated.

Comment: I haven't tried it, so cannot answer that.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to have worked after a restart. The sub-keys were there but I tried this in the order specified so not sure if they were created in the first step. I would upvote your answer if I could!